# How do I get a dialog input with 2 buttons to auto execute after timeout if no input action?

Tags: applescript, automator

I load an automator.app on my MacBook on startup that connects my MacBook to my local server. I created it with a dialog box that allows me to 'connect' or 'cancel' this script. This has been working, but at times I wish it would automatically input "connect" after 60 seconds.

I'm not really versed in AppleScript and have build most of my automator (app) routines I use from information I find on the internet and modify until it works. The following code works, sort of. It redraws the dialog box ever 5 seconds and I just want the numerics (wait_time variable) updated without a complete redraw of the dialog box. If I can do that I can have it update every 1 second. Next and more important, when I select the default button "Connect Now" nothing happens. The "Don't Connect" button seems to work fine. After this part of the script runs, I connect to specific folder on my local server and all of that works fine.

```
set theDialogText1 to "You will be connected to the Local Server in "
set wait_time to "60"
set theDialogText2 to " seconds. If your are not on the Local network; select [Don't Connect]."
repeat wait_time times
    display dialog theDialogText1 & wait_time & theDialogText2 buttons {"Don't Connect", "Connect Now"} default button "Connect Now" cancel button "Don't Connect" giving up after 5
    set wait_time to wait_time - 5
end repeat
```

I would like this to function like the 'shut down' dialog works in macOS.
Display what is happening, offer a button to run the action sooner, offer a button to cancel the function, and run the function automatically in 60 seconds if no input is received.

Answer (score 1):

Applescript only offers simple dialog, then you can't display a count down of remaining seconds with simple Applescript command. There is a progression bar display, but that display has no button.

The easiest is to use a standard dialog box with instruction "giving up after x" which closes the dialog after x seconds if the user does not react before. You just have to check if the dialog has been closed with the gave up boolean = true or check which button has been used to close it. The script bellow handles the 3 cases (waiting time 3 seconds for test)

```
set wait_time to 3
set feedback to display dialog "test time out" buttons {"Don't connect", "Connect"} giving up after wait_time

if gave up of feedback then
    display alert "no user action after " & wait_time & " seconds."
else if button returned of feedback is "Connect" then
    display alert "User clicks on Connect"
else
    display alert "User clicks on don't connect"
end if
```

You can also put this in an handler (= sub routine) and set wait_time to 3 seconds and call it several times. The script becomes a bit more complex, this is why I added few comments :

```
set Refresh_time to 3 -- the delay between 2 refresh of the dialog
set wait_time to 21 --total delay for user to decide
set Decision to 0
repeat until (Decision > 0) or (wait_time = 0)
    set Decision to Get_User_Feedback(wait_time, Refresh_time)
    set wait_time to wait_time - Refresh_time
end repeat

display alert "Decision is " & Decision
-- 0 means no answer
-- 1 means Connect
-- 2 means don't connect

-- your program here

on Get_User_Feedback(Remain_time, Step_delay)
    set feedback to display dialog "Do you want to connect. Time left is " & Remain_time & " Sec." buttons {"Don't connect", "Connect"} giving up after Step_delay  
    if gave up of feedback then
        return 0
    else if button returned of feedback is "Connect" then
        return 1
    else
        return 2
    end if
end Get_User_Feedback
```

the Get_User_Feedback is called several times in the repeat loop. It displays the dialog for 3 seconds, then close and recall again showing the new remain time. After total wait_time, or if user uses a button before, the repeat loop stops.

Comment: This post was a buy 1 get 1 free for me. Not only did I get `giving up` but also `buttons`. Thank you.